# How to get binary file using eclipse c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, binary, elf

I need to get `.hex` file from `eclipse c++` compiler. I received only `.elf` file.
Eventually, I should write that binary code into controller which can adopt only binary code.

I converted the `.elf` file to binary file using an utility, but it's not the way.

Oh, I forgot to say that I used `atollic truestudio`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Elf is "binary" file (you probably mean compiled executable). You can load that to controller using jtag/debugger. With GNU toolchain you can use objcopy to convert .elf to raw binary. Objcopy can be added as another compilation step in Eclipse/cdt, but probably your IDE provider should do this (check if there is no option to enable this already there).

Answer (score 1):

For Intel 32 bit Hex:
    fromelf -i32 Main.axf > Main.i32

For Motorola 32 bit hex:
    fromelf -m32 Main.axf > Main.m32

For Verilog byte oriented hex format:
    fromelf -vhx Main.axf > Main.vhx

For plain binary:
    fromelf -bin Main.axf > Main.bin

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse(based) C/C++ IDE you can set "**Output format**" under `Project -> Properies` window in `C/C++ Build > Settings`

```
[x] Convert build output
```

Where you can select "Inter hex" or "bin"

Pics for similar setting see [mcuoneclipse blog](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/04/11/gnu-additional-tools-create-flash-image-print-size-and-extended-listing-options/).